# AND OR combinations in Django ORM

Tags: django, orm

I want to translate a query like this into Django ORM:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status=1 OR (status=3 AND timestamp < ...)
```

Where `...` is a valid timestamp.

I have tried to build the `Q()` object like this:

```
Q(status=1) | Q (status=3, timestamp__lt=self.timeBeforeStatusIsUpdated)
```

and

```
completedQ = Q(status=1)
pendingQ = Q(status=3) & Q(timestamp__lt=self.timeBeforeStatusIsUpdated)

final = completedQ | pendingQ
```

Both return only the instances with `status=1`.

This feature is not very well documented in django (I use the latest version), so I'm looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Funny story. Both versions are right and working. The error lied somewhere else.